# How to redefine custom shortcut to open Terminal once Terminator was installed?

Tags: gnome-terminal, terminator

For Ubuntu Desktop **22.04**, with the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> shortcut is opened the default terminal available.

Now `Terminator` was installed and with the same shorcut now `Terminator` is opened instead. I did do a research in `Preferences` for each one and does not exist a shortcut to define how to open each one. Only their respective internal shortcuts.

Through:

- *Settings* -> *Keyboard* -> *Keyboard Shortcuts* -> *View and Customize Shortcuts* -> *Custom Shortcuts* was defined <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> for `Terminator` and works.

**But** <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> remains for `Terminator` yet.

Through

- *Settings* -> *Keyboard* -> *Keyboard Shortcuts* -> *View and Customize Shortcuts* ->  *Launchers* I can see the `Launch terminal` option defined with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> but is not possible edit to indicate use `Terminal`

How to Fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your keyboard settings in the shortcuts you might see something like `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator` or `Launch terminal` being assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

So, you will need to update the `x-terminal-emulator` default.  You can do it by running `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` from the current terminal:

*Example:*

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There are 7 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper   40        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/qterminal                40        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  7            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Make sure to choose the terminal application you want as your default.

Comment: Thanks, the GUI was not possible, pls could you consider in share a Figure? The command approach worked, btw is mandatory use `sudo`  otherwise is not possible apply the new settings. Therefore consider to update your command.

Comment: @ManuelJordan Updated the answer.  :)

Comment: Thank you, I asked for the Figure because I assumed that `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator` should appear in the GUI in some place as `Ctrl+Alt+T` does too. Therefore only appears the latter.

Comment: @ManuelJordan I wrote the answer based on using the installation of the Xfce4 desktop (Xubuntu) that I run, but the command to set it is identical.  So, to add in the image I had to load up the GNOME Desktop (which is not my preferred desktop) and get a snapshot of the window.  No worries though, it wasn't a big deal to get it.  Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks again for the polite and quick support. Thanks for the clarification too. Have an excellent day you too!